# Notification Center stuck over ¾ of the screen, so can't power off

Tags: ios, ipod-touch, notifications

My notifications are blocking it ¾ of the way and it really sucks. I thought it might have had something to do with the really laggy server I was on in Minecraft, but apparently not, because I saw the other question.

Is there any way to turn an iPod touch off without needing the slide to power off?

<sup>iPod touch 5th generation</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can try this method:

1. Hold the **power button** and the **home button simulatenously**.
2. Keep them pressed until the display turns off. Release both buttons immediately.

It may be tricky to pull this off as the iPod touch **will reboot if you hold the buttons too long**.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the last sentence. Rebooting is what you're intending to do by holding both buttons?

Comment: In order to reboot an iPhone/iPod touch you can press and hold the power button and the home button. The screen will turn black and after a few seconds you will see the Apple logo on a white or black background. Once you see the Apple your device is already restarting. However, if you press both buttons until the screen goes black and release both buttons you can turn off the device without rebooting it.